# LINQ many to many relationship - get a list of grouped objects

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, many-to-many, left-join

I have a bit of a complicated one (for me anyway):

I have 2 entities in a many to many relationship.

```
Projects       {Project_Id, ProjectName}
Users          {User_Id, UserName} 
Projects-Users {Id, Project_Id, User_id}
```

A project can be assigned to more users.

Now I want to retrieve the List of all projects (listed once) with Project_id, Name, ListOfAssignedUsers:

```
Id  ProjectName  Users
1   Project1     U1, U2, U3
2   Project2     
3   Project3     U1
```

I can do this IN SQL, but can't figure out how to do it in LINQ!

It's LINQ to Entity - Framework(DB first):
My classes look like this:

public partial class Projects
    {
        public Projects()
        {
            this.Users = new HashSet();
        }

```
    public int Project_Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Users> Users { get; set; }
}
```

public partial class Users
    {
        public Users()
        {
            this.Projects = new HashSet();
        }

```
    public int User_Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Projects> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

(I made the change with removing the id from Projects-Users and made the combo (Project_Id, User_id) the primary key of that.

Comment: LINQ to what?  Entity Framework?  We need some code such as what your entity classes look like, what you've tried etc.  I'd expect a `Project` to have a `Users` navigation property on it, which pretty much solves your problem.

Comment: I would also recommend removing the id field in Project-Users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the list of all the projects with the assigned users:

```
var projects= from p in db.Projects select new{ project_Id = p.Project_Id, projectName = p.ProjectName, userList = p.Projects-Users.Select(pu=>pu.Users.UserName).ToList()};
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Id field from the Project-Users table.  The primary key if you need one should be {Project_Id,User_id}.  There should be (if not already) a foreign key constraint between Projects.Project_Id and Project-Users.Project_Id and another FK between Users.User_Id and Project-Users.User_id

If you have your model mapped in Entity Framework, then you reference it like this:

```
var result=context.Project.Include(p=>p.Users);
```

You can dump the results like this:

```
foreach(var record in result)
{
  Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}",
    record.Project_Id,
    record.ProjectName,
    String.Join(",",record.Users.Select(u=>u.UserName)));
}
```

Comment: hmm, are you sure, I tried that and can't do the  
var result=context.Project.Include(p=>p.Users);   I used EF6 Database first to map the entities. They work separately,  but not to include the users.

Comment: It might be `var result=context.Projects.Include(p=>p.Users);`, but yes, the idea is correct.  Do it all the time.  If you've set up your database like I suggested, then it really is that simple.  If you don't remove the Id from the Project-Users table, it becomes more complicated.  Or if you don't have the foreign keys set up.